# How to export value output without '@{}' after string replacement?

Tags: string, powershell, replace, output

I'm trying to export forward list from Exchange 365 and remove "smtp:" string from output.

Here is PS code for Exchange 365 forwards list:

```
$forwards = Get-Mailbox –ResultSize Unlimited |
            where {($_.ForwardingSmtpAddress –ne $null)} |
            select identity, *forward*
$result = $forwards -replace "smtp:",""
$result
```

My `$forwards` value has format:

```
PS> $forwards
Identity      DeliverToMailboxAndForward ForwardingAddress ForwardingSmtpAddress
--------      -------------------------- ----------------- ---------------------
name.surname1                       True                   smtp:name.surname1@domain.com
name.surname2                       True                   smtp:name.surname2@domain.com
name.surname3                       True                   smtp:name.surname3@domain.com
```

I managed to remove that `smtp:` text with command:

```
$result = $forwards -replace "smtp:",""
```

But I get such ugly output for that variable:

```
PS> $result
@{Identity=name.surname1; DeliverToMailboxAndForward=True; ForwardingAddress=; ForwardingSmtpAddress=name.surname1@domain.com}
@{Identity=name.surname2; DeliverToMailboxAndForward=True; ForwardingAddress=; ForwardingSmtpAddress=name.surname2@domain.com}
@{Identity=name.surname3; DeliverToMailboxAndForward=True; ForwardingAddress=; ForwardingSmtpAddress=name.surname3@domain.com}
```

How to get rid of that `@{}` and present it right way as it was in `$forwards` variable? Maybe there is better way to remove `smtp:` from first value `$forwards`?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result?

Comment: @vonPryz I want to present output in same way as it is with $forwards variable with columns and without  that @{;} signs.

Comment: I meant, do you want to print it on console, save to a file, process further on the pipeline or something else?

Comment: @vonPryz print it to console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new variable it might be easier to modify the existing objects in your array. You need to do the replacement on each `ForwardingSmtpAddress` property:

```
$forwards | Foreach-Object {
    $_.ForwardingSmtpAddress = $_.ForwardingSmtpAddress -replace "smtp:", ""
}
```

After this, just echoing `$forwards` to the screen should show you the updated values.

Comment: That did a trick :) but do You know if this is possible to fix that $result variable to be presented in same right way?

Comment: It is but it's probably not worth the hassle due to the way objects work in powershell. You'd need to deep clone the object. If you *really* want to use `$result` you could say `$result = $forwards`, but this will create a reference between the two, i.e. changes to `$result` will be reflected in `$forwards`

Comment: So is this object broken - it's impossible to remove that signs @{} and fix column output?

Comment: The object is not broken. What are you trying to do with the output? Like I said, you should only operate on the `$forwards` array, forget about assigning it to anything else.

Comment: I wrote it wrong :) it's not broken but I don't know how to write that variable to output ( console ) with correct format.

Answer (score 4):

You should also be able to use calculated properties:

```
$forwards = Get-Mailbox –resultSize unlimited |
            where { $_.ForwardingSmtpAddress –ne $null } |
            select @{Name="Identity";Expression={$_.Identity}},
                DeliverToMailboxAndForward, ForwardingAddress,
                @{Name="ForwardingSmtpAddress";Expression={$_.ForwardingSmtpAddress -replace "smtp:",""}}
```

I don't have the means to test this right now, though.

Comment: Identity value is lost - empty column.

Comment: Damn. What happens if you only try `Expression={$_.Identity}` or `Expression={$_.Identity.toString()}`?

Comment: This one: Expression={$_.Identity}   is ok :)

Answer (score 0):

What would be the result when you use this snippet?

```
$forwards = Get-Mailbox –resultSize unlimited |
            where {$_.ForwardingSmtpAddress –ne $null} |
            select Identity, DeliverToMailboxAndForward, ForwardingAddress,
                @{Name='ForwardingSmtpAddress';Expression={$_.ForwardingSmtpAddress.ToString().Replace('smtp:', $null)}}
```

If you don't wan't the `@{}` maybe you could convert or export it to a CSV format.

```
Export-Csv -Delimiter ';'
ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';'
```